# Efficient way to update a database via an ETL process?

Tags: java, database, performance

I have this workflow that extracts components from a source (e.g., a sourcecode repo). It then compares them with the persisted components in a database and propagates any additions, modifications, and deletions. I have the following algo:

```
propagate(components) {
    
    // Bulk replace
    for (component in components) {
     componentName = component.getName();
     if !componentPersistence.get(componentName).equals(componentName)
        componentPersistence.update(component);
     else
        componentPersistence.add(component);
    }

    componentPersistence.deleteAllExcept(components);    
}
```

What is a more efficient implementation of this program?

Comment: why is this tagged with java?

Answer (score 0):

I think one approach is something like this:

1. insert all components into a temporary table (temp_components)
2. delete all components that not exists in temp_components

> ```
> delete from components c
> where not exists (select 1 from temp_components t where t.name =
> c.name)
> ```

3. update all components that exists in temp_components

> ```
> update components c
> set field = (select t.field from temp_components t where t.name = c.name)
> where exists (
>  select 1 from temp_components t where t.name = c.name
> )
> ```

4. insert all temp_components that not exists in components table

> ```
> insert into components (name, field)
> select t.name, t.field
> from temp_compoments t
> where not exists (
>  select 1 from component c where c.name = t.name
> )
> ```

5. delete the temporary table

If you are using oracle, the insert and update can be made with the MERGE operation.